# Restricting an input box to only numbers 0-9

Tags: javascript

How can one restrict an inputbox to just use numbers only.

So if a user were to type in anything from a-z, it will not work in the inputbox.

To some this may seem easy but to me, it sounds like rocket science.

no jQuery please.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>

<input type="text" id="numbersonly" />

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Here's [one duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/469357/778118), and [another](http://stackoverflow.com/q/995183/778118), and [another](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14585407/778118)... This question has been asked dozens of times.

Comment: <input type="text" onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57 && document.querySelector('#txtbox').value +(event.keyCode-48) <= 174" />

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You could use an input with the HTML5 `number` type

```
<input type="number" />
```

or javascript, as an input with a `number` type doesn't [really limit](http://jsfiddle.net/JVLkw/1/) input to numbers only :

```
document.getElementById('numbersonly').addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    var key   = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;

    if (!( [8, 9, 13, 27, 46, 110, 190].indexOf(key) !== -1 ||
         (key == 65 && ( e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey  ) ) || 
         (key >= 35 && key <= 40) ||
         (key >= 48 && key <= 57 && !(e.shiftKey || e.altKey)) ||
         (key >= 96 && key <= 105)
       )) e.preventDefault();
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/JVLkw/161/)

Comment: I encountered a Firefox browser with this proposed solution when entering % or ^ & or *. This solution accepted those characters. Thanks.

Comment: Java Script doesn't work with numeric keys and even doesn't work backspace

Comment: This answer is a good start but has a couple of critical flaws: (1) you cannot use the backspace, delete, or arrow keys to adjust the input, and (2) it allows non-numeric characters when pressing the `shift` or `ctrl` key plus a number (e.g., @, #, $). Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995183/how-to-allow-only-numeric-0-9-in-html-inputbox-using-jquery#answer-995193

Comment: in Typescript keycode is deprecated. can you suggest me another way

Comment: I'm looking for a solution, too. Since number type accepts +, -, ., and 'e', and like the OP, I only want digits 0-9 (as in the case of a student ID number). So. on change or input, parse the new string and remove these offending characters. Not sure about backspace, etc.. yet...

Answer (score 6):

Using HTML5

```
<input type="number">
```

You can also use [**Modernizr**](http://modernizr.com/) for backwards compatibility