# How Value add in Array<string | RegExp> in Angular2

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, masking

I have Face one problem in Angular2 & RegExp

This Package Used in Angular 2 
https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask/

Documentation 
https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask/tree/master/angular2#readme

My Problem I can used 5-6 type Phone Format used

Like

- (XXX) XXX XXXX
- (XXX) XXX-XXXX
- XXX-XXX-XXXX
- XXX XXX XXXX
- XXXXXXXXXX
- XXXXX XXXXX

Above Package used Array Format

I have String this format

```
'(', /[1-9]/, /\d/, /\d/, ')', ' ', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, '-', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/
```

How I can add in Array Format

I can try this code

Code-1:

```
var phoneFormat:Array<string | RegExp>;
 var format="'(','/[1-9]/','/\d/','/\d/',')',' ','/\d/','/\d/','/\d/',' ','/\d/','/\d/','/\d/','/\d/'";

        var ArrayObj=format.split(',');

       for ( var i = 0; i < ArrayObj.length; i++ ) {
          phoneFormat.push(ArrayObj[i]); 
        }
```

Error Given:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

Code-2

```
 var format=['(','/[1-9]/','/\d/','/\d/',')',' ','/\d/','/\d/','/\d/',' ','/\d/','/\d/','/\d/','/\d/'];
       phoneFormat=format;
```

Code-2 No Error But masking not working

Comment: `var phoneFormat:Array<string | RegExp>;` this is just a type definition. You have not initialized the variable. Try `var phoneFormat:Array<string | RegExp> = [];`

Comment: this also try no success

Comment: Lets clean comments sections and remove anything that is non constructive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented, you are getting following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

because, you have not initialized the array.

`var phoneFormat:Array<string | RegExp>;` is just type definition. You will have to do `var phoneFormat:Array<string | RegExp> = [];`

---

Now

```
"'(','/[1-9]/','/\d/','/\d/',')',' ','/\d/','/\d/','/\d/',' ','/\d/','/\d/','/\d/','/\d/'"
```

is a string of formatted string. So when you split it, you will only get stringified string like `"'('"`.

You will have to parse it. Following sample will help:

```js
var phoneFormat: Array <string | RegExp> = [];
var format = "'(','/[1-9]/','/\d/','/\d/',')',' ','/\d/','/\d/','/\d/',' ','/\d/','/\d/','/\d/','/\d/'";

format.split(',').forEach(function(value){
  if(value.startsWith('\'/')) {
    phoneFormat.push(new RegExp(value.substring(2, value.length-2)));
  }
  else {
    phoneFormat.push(value.substring(1, value.length-1));
  }
});

console.log(phoneFormat)
```

Comment: i can success but i can type  only "d" charcter(letter) no other character type :(

Comment: i want only [0-9] number othre ASCII Charcter Allow how i can do this can you suggest me ??

Comment: You can use `input` event on textbox and check for new value. If new value satisfies regex, continue else set previous value

Comment: Thanks you i can success its big help to me last four day try it different code  but not success

Comment: You can refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18156824/restricting-an-input-box-to-only-numbers-0-9